# Octave false position

Tags: numerical-methods, integer-programming, octave

i'm try to write some code in octave based in false position method.

So, here it is:

[image: this is the code]

And I get the follow error:

"parse error near line 40 of file C:\Users\HP...falsa.m

syntax error

else"

So, the point here, is that I actually know the meaning "parse error near the line 40" warning (it means something octave cannot understand). But a already tried to fixed and i´m still get the error.

What i'm  missing?

Thanks for any help.
Actually, i´m think my code is not very efficient. Some help would be great. Thanks again.

Comment: A comment about your code: the two branches of the `if fun(x0) < 0` are nearly identical. You can replace `if z < 0` with `if fun(x0)*z > 0`. Then, you can get rid of the `if fun(x0) < 0` and the entire else branch. Fewer lines of code means fewer places for bugs to hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `if` statement, `if fun(x0)<0`, has no corresponding `endif`, which should go before the `else` on line 40.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a silly mistake.